# Locking planes together and animating them separately with shape keys

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, mesh, workflow

I have several images-as-planes in Cycles that make a face.  I want to lock them all together so I can move them as a group while animating them separately with shape keys.  How can i do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (sortof) do it like this

1. set the pivot point for all the planes in the same exact point in 3d space.
2. this can be done in more then one way: you can join all them togheter (so that all meshes get one single pivot point) and then separate them back again, one by one (the pivot point of separated meshes remains untouched); another one would be manually "set origins" to one 3d point of your choice...
3. then select one plane as "base" and use "copy location" constraint on all the others, with the "base" one as target.

[image]

[image]

4. the constrained planes can't be moved anymore, if not moving the "base" one, which moves all the others too.
5. shape keys for each plane are still independent
6. for rotation/scale, just select all them, they will rotate/scale around the same pivot point for all so they will rotate/scale all together

Comment: Please, how do i select one plane as base and use copy location constraint?  Thank you!

Comment: I mant this: once all planes have the pivot in the same exact 3d space point, you have to make one of them to be the base point, say "plane1". All you have to do is select another plane, "plane2" add a a"copy location" constraint (in the rigth tabs, constraints), and select "plane1". I added some image above.